# Keep ID separately from object

Tags: java, oop, orm, model

I have a Java object *user* that is stored in a database with a primary key. For example:

```
id | login | name | surname
---------------------------
0  | admin | Bob  | Marley
1  | ..... | .... | ......
```

There are `addUser`, `getUserById`, `editUser` and other API operations that can be called by a Java client of my application. Each such request is composed as a Java object, for example:

```
class EditRequest {  
  User newUserProfile; 
}
```

I have a problem with defining a model for these operations: should I use one object `User` with four fields `id`, `log`, `name`, and `surname` for all operations or should I separate them to `User` and `UserValue`, where the second object contains all the fields except ID. The reason why the second object does not contain ID is that it is intended to be used in the `addUser` operation in which all fields are passed from the client side except ID since the ID is generated for new users on the server side. This separation will allow me to construct an object `UserValue` on the client instead of, for example, creating an instance of `User` with null ID field. The third way to solve it would be to always keep User and ID separately and use Map to bind them together when necessary. What would be the best option?

Answer (score 2):

The 'standard' approach is to have just one object for each table (Entity). If you look at how the [Java Persistence API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html) approach this is that you create one object. The primary key field is null for objects that have not yet been persisted to the database.

Having separate objects representing the same entity creates confusion and repetition of code. Each time you have to add a new field you have to add in 2 places, and risk mismatching or forgetting to update the other place.

I would seriously consider using an off the shelf ORM package which implements JPA (such as Hibernate or EclipseLink) instead of doing things yourself. You'll just take ages and implement only a small fraction of what these frameworks provide out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Each approach has pros and cons.  personally, i would keep the id with the object as that will always be useful to the object.  if you look at pretty much any ORM (e.g. hibernate), you will almost always see objects being created as simple POJOs with id fields, where null is used for new objects which haven't had an id assigned yet.  while this may not be the perfect solution, it is the one i would choose as i believe it has the most pros and fewest cons.